# Fixing footer to the bottom of a page

Tags: html, css

How can I fix my footer to the bottom of the page while centered? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I want the footer to sit at the bottom of the page in the center at 50%, but the margin-left and right isn't working for some reason. It's sitting towards the left.

```css
.navigation2 {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #888;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="navigation2">
    &copy; 2019 - <a href="index.html">X</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can accept ryantdecker's answer by hovering to the left of the answer and clicking the checkmark that appears on hover. Both you and the answerer will gain reputation by doing so! :) Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: BTW, If that line is everything that is in the footer, you don't need to add an additional div inside the footer.  footer is a native tag that can be styled in css using footer{/*your style here*/} Just a point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may just need a little bit different approach to the math.  This may get you closer to what you're looking for:

CSS:

```
.navigation2 {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color:#888;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Another way you could do it that's more dynamic (works whatever the width of your footer) and scales better so your footer isn't squeezed as much on small screens:

```
.navigation2 {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color:#888;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translatex(-50%);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I didn't know margin-left and right could work like that. Looks like I need to keep practicing my CSS. Thanks again

Comment: no problem - there are probably a half dozen other ways to do it...which one is 'correct' really just depends on how you want it to be have when either the footer or the screen/window change in size.